# Formating all lines of string (even when \n is in the string)

Tags: python

I have a `list` that contains strings, and some have `\n` in them.

My problem is that when I print the list and add a `\t`, it only works for the first line. I need the `\t` to apply to all lines of the printed index.

I have added the `\t` at the `"t = "` line but it only applies this to the first instance.
Not sure what I am missing.

```
mylist = [
  ['Example of a string', 'more words and more words'],
  ["This is an example of a string .\nBut this is a new line \nIt should all be foramted the same!" ,'Blah blah blah blah'],
]

templist = []
for text in mylist:
    t = "--"+text[1]+"--\n"+"\"" + "\t" +text[0] + "\""
    templist.append(t)
for text in templist:
    print(text)
```

--CURRENT OUTPUT--

```
>>>--more words and more words--                                                                                                                                                      
"[TAB] Example of a string"                                                                                                                                                       
--Blah blah blah blah--                                                                                                                                                            
"[TAB] This is an example of a string .                                                                                                                                           
But this is a new line                                                                                                                                                             
It should all be foramted the same!"
```

--DESIRED OUTPUT--

```
>>>>--more words and more words--                                                                                                                                                      
[TAB] "Example of a string"                                                                                                                                                       
--Blah blah blah blah--                                                                                                                                                            
[TAB]"This is an example of a string .                                                                                                                                           
[TAB] But this is a new line                                                                                                                                                             
[TAB] It should all be foramted the same!"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite unclear exactly what you want and why but from your examples, simply replace `text[0]` with `text[0].replace('\n', '\n\t')` to get tabs after every newline in the blocked text. You get the result you seem to want.

```
--more words and more words--
"   Example of a string"
--Blah blah blah blah--
"   This is an example of a string .
    But this is a new line 
    It should all be foramted the same!"
```

which seems to be the desired result. But again - I would recommend structuring your data in a more intuitive way. Like as a dictionary that maps these headings to a list of sentences to show below.

Answer (score 0):

You can just unpack them in names, that way its WAY easier to read and understand.

Also, [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) will seperate a string by newlines

```
for text, title in mylist:
    text = '\t'.join(text.splitlines(True))
    print(f'--{title}--\n\t"{text}"')
    #print('--{}--\n\t"{}"'.format(title, text)
```

This will print as desired:

```
--Example of a string--
    "more words and more words"
--Blah blah blah blah--
    "This is an example of a string .
    But this is a new line
    It should all be foramted the same!"
```